# What are main difference between Subscription Key and OAth 2.0 in Azure API Management?

Tags: azure-api-management

I'm looking for a away to protect my APIs in APIM, I really don't understand the difference between Subscription Key and OAuth 2.0 using Access Token. Can we use OAuth2.0 instead of Subscription Key or use both ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I use OAuth Token as an alternative to Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49617794/can-i-use-oauth-token-as-an-alternative-to-ocp-apim-subscription-key)

Comment: [Protecting APIs in Azure API Management using OAuth 2.0 Client Credential Flow & test using Postman](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/fasttrack-for-azure/protecting-apis-in-azure-api-management-using-oauth-2-0-client/ba-p/3054130) and [Protect API's using OAuth 2.0 in APIM](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-paas-blog/protect-api-s-using-oauth-2-0-in-apim/ba-p/2309538)

Answer (score 2):

As per my understanding,
In Simple:

**Subscription keys** are the common way to access the Azure APIs in APIM instance.

If the API requires **subscription key** to access it by the user, then we call it as **secured API**. Otherwise, it is unsecured API and mostly used by the public.

But for unsecured access to that certain APIs, configuring **another mechanism** to **secure client access** is recommended.

Those other mechanisms to secure access to APIs in APIM were ***OAuth 2.0***, ***Client Certificates***, and ***Restring caller IPs***.

As DeepDave recommended this [SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49617794/can-i-use-oauth-token-as-an-alternative-to-ocp-apim-subscription-key) states that,

> It is not possible to use OAuth token to identify client, but you can use it for rate-limiting and logging (of sorts).

You can identify the users and their level of access (To how many products/APIs, they have access) easily by using **subscription keys** because they are associated on 3 scopes like Product level, All APIs level, or an individual level.

**OAuth 2.0** provides extra layer of security both in Authentication and Authorization.

**To Implement the other mechanisms like OAuth2.0 or other, these references are useful**:

- [Protect APIM using OAuth2.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-protect-backend-with-aad)
- [API Protecting Mechanisms in Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-subscriptions#what-are-subscriptions)
- [A Workaround of Protecting APIs in Azure API Management using OAuth 2.0 Client Credential Flow & test using Postman](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/fasttrack-for-azure/protecting-apis-in-azure-api-management-using-oauth-2-0-client/ba-p/3054130)
- [Extra layer of security to avoid unauthorized access to APIs using OAuth 2.0](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-paas-blog/protect-api-s-using-oauth-2-0-in-apim/ba-p/2309538)